# Copy stdin to stdout in pure Bash

Tags: bash, stdout, stdin

I'm looking for a **pure Bash** solution to copy the data from the standard input of the function to standard output, without processing it.

The goal is to decorate the input by outputting some text before and after it.

The cleanest solution is to use the `cat` or the `tee` binaries. But, as requested, the solution has to be in pure Bash.

## My current solution

For now, my solution is to use the `read` builtin:

```
decorate() {
    local line

    printf '%s' "<"

    while IFS= read -r line; do
        printf '%s\n' "$line"
    done

    if ((${#line} > 0)); then
        printf '%s' "$line"
    fi

    printf '%s' ">"
}
```

```
$ printf '%s\n' "foo" "bar" "baz" | decorate
<foo
bar
baz
>
```

### Cons

- The data is read line by line,
- the data is assigned to a variable,
- the last line (if not ended by a newline) need to be handled especially.

This solution might be acceptable if I needed to process the input. But it seems overkill because I just need to pass stdin data to stdout.

## The current lead (from jpmam1)

I tried to use a redirection:

```
decorate() {
    printf '%s' "<" "$(</dev/stdin)" ">"
}
```

### Pros

- The code is more concise,
- everything is read in one time.

### Cons

- When data from stdin ends with a newline, it is not preserved:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "foo" "bar" "baz" | decorate
<foo
bar
baz>
```

```
$ echo $'\n\n\n\n' | decorate
<>
```

Comment: Why not just `cat /dev/stdin`?

Comment: Why are you requesting a "pure bash" solution? Why not use `cat`? Shell scripting without using any common utilities is like eating without utensils. It can be done, but why would you want to?

Comment: Note that files can contain NUL bytes but strings can't. It's really awkward to work around that impedance mismatch.

Comment: Why bash......?

Comment: Quoting: "The goal is to decorate the input by outputting some text before and after it" and "just need to pass stdin data to stdout" seem to contradict each other.   Also, your cons annotations "The shell processes data" and "loop and conditional constructs are used" suddenly pop up and appear to be other prerequisites. Maybe the question "what are you trying to do" is in order.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Why not ? Why relying on external program if it can be done easily using the shell ? There is good reasons to do it both ways. Regarding your analogy, eating without utensils is sometimes handy. I t depends on what you're eating.

Comment: @Roadowl I edited my question and my code sample trying to better illustrate what I are asking for.

Comment: @Roadowl Why Bash ? Because I need it in a Bash script.

Comment: @Roadowl Outputting text before and after the data from stdin doesn't require to process the data (in my case). I just need to control **when** outputting the data from stdin.

Comment: @Roadowl The cons annotations are not _new_ prerequisites. My current solution just works the way I want to, perfectly. But I found it too complicated and asked me "Isn't it a more elegant way to do that ?" I thank about how redirecting input and output is simple in Bash but didn't find a way to redirect stdin to stdout.

Comment: To clarify, what's wrong with `printf '%s' "<" "$(<"/dev/stdin")" ">"` ?

Comment: @jpmam1 The final newline is lost.

Comment: @DamienFlament : `$(<...)` returns the whole input, including all newlines. If you need an additional newline somewhere, just add it. As far I can see, the solution by jpmam1 fulfils all your requirements, including that of simplicity and elegance.

Comment: @user1934428 It seems that `$(<...)` strips the final newlines. I edited the question to better illustrate that.

Comment: @DamienFlament : Could it be that `printf` is to be blamed here? I can't test it using your `/dev/stdin` trick, because this is not supported on my platform, but I used the construct to feed an existing file, named _cio_, which happens to have a final newline: `bash -c 'FOO=$(<tmp/cio); xxd <<<"$FOO"'`, and this shows the newline. But when I replace the _xxd_  command by `printf %s "$FOO"`, the newline is missing.